# Sql remove duplicate when select table

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have a table in my sql that have names and cities for example.

I want to make a Select Command that get all the cities and remove from the result the duplicates.

for the select i am using:

```
        string citiesSelect = "SELECT [city] FROM [people] ORDER BY [city]";
        CitiesDataSource.SelectCommand = citiesSelect;
        CitiesDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        DropDownList2.DataSourceID = CitiesDataSource.ID;
```

Comment: you can either go for distinct or with group by option....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp).

```
 string citiesSelect = "SELECT DISTINCT [city] FROM [people] ORDER BY [city]";
        CitiesDataSource.SelectCommand = citiesSelect;
        CitiesDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        DropDownList2.DataSourceID = CitiesDataSource.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following line:

```
string citiesSelect = "SELECT DISTINCT [city] FROM [people] ORDER BY [city]";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [city] FROM [people] ORDER BY [city]
```

The documentation for DISTINCT can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).